# Postgres Analyze Command took 1 hour 30 mins for single table on moderate size RDS

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

**Issue:** Postgres one table took 1 hour 30 mins just to analyze for default statistics target of 100.

1. Why?
2. How we can predict this time in future?
3. Is there any way to speed it up for such tables

**Current Setup:**
Postgres version: 12.4
Fresh instance restored from snapshot on AWS and then upgraded to 12.4
VCPU: 4
RAM: 16 GB
IOPS:3000
Relation size: 23 GB
Relation total size: 139 GB
Table Size: 83 GB
reltuples: 1.21582e+07

Is it because of large size of toast?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not normal.

Unless your system is very, very slow, the problem was probably an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock that someone had taken on the table and never released.

Comment: There was no exclusive lock / deadlock / blocked and blocking events. Can it not be because of toast size.... table size is 83 and relation sze 23 GB so there are 50GB of toast... that means for 60% of records it has to go to toast table and then mark free at dead tuples location for tuples of arbitrary length?

Comment: No, it cannot be TOAST size either. You'll have to look at `pg_stat_activity` while the `ANALYZE` is running. Impossible to diagnose with this little information.